# WCF consumed by Web Farm Server. Error: The socket connection was aborted

Tags: .net, wcf, sockets, binding, tcp

I have a WCF service deployed on ServerA. I am using tcp binding.

I also have a web farm which consists of ServerB and ServerC.

When I deploy my application which consumes the WCF service on any of the servers ServerB or ServerC, I get an error when trying to call my service. I added tracing and this is the error I get:

> The socket connection was aborted. This could be caused by an error
>   processing your message or a receive timeout being exceeded by the
>   remote host, or an underlying network resource issue. Local socket
>   timeout was '10675199.02:48:05.4775807'.

I tried to consume the same service from my pc and it works fine. I also tried to deploy the application on other servers which arent on the web farm, but are on the same network and I am also able to consume my service.

So I figured out the problem is related to the fact Servers B and C are on a web farm. This is just a guess, but I couldnt find any other reason for this behavior.

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If the servers are behind a load balancer you may have to do the following (useRequestHeadersForMetadataAddress ):

```
<serviceBehaviors>
  <behavior name="YourServiceBehavior">
    <useRequestHeadersForMetadataAddress />
  </behavior>
</serviceBehaviors>
```

Comment: The OP is not getting the error during "Add Service Reference". Would the above affect the OP at runtime?